# Spec are failing on Travis Ci, and are green locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, travis-ci

I'm using Rspec on my Rails App (5.2.3)
All my test are green locally, but they are failing on travis.ci
Below a part of the error and my travis config. Hope you could help.

The main error is

```
ArgumentError:
        SMTP To address may not be blank: []
```

Here is the error with more details... How does it come that it passes locally and not on Travis???

```
45.84s$ bundle exec rails spec
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/ruby -I/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib:/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
Randomized with seed 28885
....FFFFFFFF.F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-27.450.html
.F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-27.997.html
****.............WARNING: The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.6.
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.1 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:45832
F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-32.656.html
  Image screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-32.656.png
.............*...**....F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-38.949.html
..........F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-42.247.html
  Image screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-07-09-13-42.247.png
*......................................F...F  HTML screenshot: /home/travis/build/knop/kamelot/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2019-05-25-00-00-00.000.html
.............


  1) Returnings showing a returning displays the order's date and returning's limit date
     Failure/Error: ReturningMailer.send_returning(self).deliver_now

     ArgumentError:
       SMTP To address may not be blank: []
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:21:in `check_to'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:7:in `check'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/test_mailer.rb:38:in `deliver!'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:2159:in `do_delivery'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `block in deliver'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `deliver'
     # ./app/models/returning.rb:37:in `send_email_with_status'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:18:in `create'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/features/admin/returnings/returnings_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

here is my config  `.travis.yml`

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.4.4

addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"


before_install:
  - gem install bundler -v '>= 2'
  - "echo 'gem: --no-document' > ~/.gemrc"
  - "echo '--colour' > ~/.rspec"
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

before_script:
  - bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
  yarn: true

install:
  - bundle update --bundler
  - bundle install
  - nvm install node v11.10.0
  - node -v
  - npm i -g yarn
  - yarn

script:
  - bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
  - bundle exec rails spec
```

Returning model

```
    def send_email_with_status
        if self.pending?
            ReturningMailer.send_returning(self).deliver_now #line 37
        elsif self.confirmed?
            ReturningMailer.received_returning(self).deliver_now
        end
    end
```

### EDIT:

I added this  in config/test.rb but it is not failing anymore here. (thanks for the hint)

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Comment: What does this `./app/models/returning.rb:37` look like? Seems to me it is likely an environment configuration issue but we are missing key components to diagnose the issue here

Comment: @engineersmnky I've just added the method I have line 37

Comment: Okay can you post your action mailer configuration and can you confirm that Travis is running in the test environment

Comment: I've updated my question, how can I confirm you that Travis is running the test env? Where shall I set this ? @engineersmnky

Comment: Well given that your configuration change worked I would guess it is in the test environment :). Glad you got this sorted out